# Editing Google Charts Category Filter

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm creating a google chart to deploy as a web app, and I'm having some trouble with the category filter. I would like to be able to select multiple items at once, so that the dropdown would stay open until I've finished selecting items. The default behavior is that on each selection, the dropdown closes, which is very inconvenient when you're selecting 20-30 items from a list of a ~100.

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'controls']
});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
// passes in the data and draws it.
function drawDashboard() {

  // Create our data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
    ['Michael', 5],
    ['Elisa', 7],
    ['Robert', 3],
    ['John', 2],
    ['Jessica', 6],
    ['Aaron', 1],
    ['Margareth', 8]
  ]);

  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  // Create a range slider, passing some options
  var nameSelect = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Name'
    }
  });

  // Create a pie chart, passing some options
  var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'PieChart',
    'containerId': 'chart_div',
    'options': {
      'width': 300,
      'height': 300,
      'pieSliceText': 'value',
      'legend': 'right'
    }
  });


  dashboard.bind(nameSelect, pieChart);

  // Draw the dashboard.
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a basic jsfiddle adapted from the google documentation. http://jsfiddle.net/xcgpabju/2/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, I'm totally open to solutions other than using a category filter. However, I don't have much experience with jquery but I think I get the gist of what you're saying- make an accordion with the selectable filter list in one section. The thing I can't figure out after lots of googlin' around is how to get the list from the datatable object and make it selectable. My actual data is coming from google sheets, so coding it directly as HTML isn't practical. Do you have a simple jsfiddle with this idea implemented that I could look at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are no options that will change the default behavior of the category filter / make it stay open while selecting...

other problems can arise as well, such as having enough room to display the selected values.

another option would be to use [jquery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/) for the filter controls,
although it does require significantly more code...

see following working snippet for an example.

this uses a [selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/) to filter the chart.
following is a description for using the selectable...

> Use the mouse to select elements, individually or in a group. The plugin allows for elements to be selected by dragging a box (sometimes called a lasso) with the mouse over the elements. Elements can also be selected via click or drag while holding the ctrl/meta key, allowing for multiple (non-contiguous) selections.

the filter values are pulled from the data table using method --> `getDistinctValues`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'controls']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
    ['Michael', 5],
    ['Elisa', 7],
    ['Robert', 3],
    ['John', 2],
    ['Jessica', 6],
    ['Aaron', 1],
    ['Margareth', 8]
  ]);


  var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      chartArea: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
      },
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      legend: 'right'
    }
  });

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(pieChart, 'ready', function () {
    var filterValues = data.getDistinctValues(0);
    $.each(filterValues, function(index, value) {
      $('.selectable').append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
    });
    $('.accordion').accordion({
      active: false,
      create: function () {
        $('.selectable').selectable({
          filter: '*',
          stop: filterChart
        });
      },
      collapsible: true,
      heightStyle: 'content'
    });

    $('.button-reset').button();
    $('.button-reset').button('disable');
    $('.button-reset').on('click', clearFilter);
  });

  function filterChart() {
    var chartView = {};
    var selectedValues = [];
    $('.selectable li.ui-selected').each(function(index, selected) {
      selectedValues.push(selected.innerHTML);
    });

    if (selectedValues.length > 0) {
      $('.selectable').closest('.accordion').find('.button-reset').button('enable');
      chartView.rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 0,
        test: function (value) {
          return (selectedValues.indexOf(value) > -1);
        }
      }]);
    }

    pieChart.setView(chartView);
    pieChart.draw();
  }

  function clearFilter(sender) {
    var accordion;

    sender.preventDefault();
    sender.stopPropagation();

    accordion = $(sender.target).closest('.accordion');
    accordion.find('.selectable li').removeClass('ui-selected');
    accordion.accordion('option', 'active', false);
    $(sender.target).closest('button').button('disable');
    filterChart();

    return false;
  }

  pieChart.draw();
});
```

```css
.accordion > div.ui-accordion-content {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dashboard {
  padding: 12px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dashboard > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.selectable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.selectable li {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 8pt;
  margin-top: 2px;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px;
}

.selectable .ui-selecting {
  background-color: #99ccff;
 border: 1px solid #809fff;
}

.selectable .ui-selected {
  background-color: #007fff;
 border: 1px solid #003eff;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.ui-button-icon-only {
  float: right;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0px;
  min-width: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ui-widget {
  font-size: 8pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="accordion">
    <h3>
      <span>Name&nbsp;</span>
      <button class="button-reset ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" title="Clear filter...">
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
      </button>
    </h3>
    <div><ul class="selectable"></ul></div>
  </div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! I was able to adapt this to my code pretty easily- the only change I made that might be useful for other people with longer lists is adding  both overflow-y:scroll; and height:150px; (or whatever) to the .selectable in the css.